# Unable to get local host to work for VS2013 web app

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, localhost, iis-express

I am having a nightmare trying to run my application locally. Following various tutorials I set my project to SSL = True and updated the Project properties like so:

[image: Project Properties]

and

[image: Web Properties]

However when I run the project I get a message saying either the page cannot be displayed (IE) or the Webpage is not available (Chrome) both say ERR_CONNECTION_RESET.

I have looked at the application.config file under IIS Express in my user/document folder which show the following

[image: applicaiton.config file]

I can't see the website in any browser or page inspector.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,
Kevin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found the answer although I am not sure why it happened.

Reading up about IIS Express it seems SSL requires a port between 44300 and 44399.

For some reason VS2013, or at least my instance of it, defaulted to port 1881.

further information can be found [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/using-iis-express/handling-url-binding-failures-in-iis-express)

to change the port my project was using a edited the IIS applicationhost.config located at C:\Users\YOUR_USER\Documents\IISExpress\config

[image: screenshot]

Hope this helps anyone who is having the same issue.